When writting a yocto recipe, can I get the version info (or other meta data for) for a build dependency?
I'm writing a recipe for a package, and would like to embed the version info of a dependent library into this package.
Is there a way to fetch the meta data for build dependencies.

recipe for package

DEPENDS = "package_b"

VERSION_b = "${SRCREV:package_b}


Does it because you have multiple version of the depended package (package_b)? If that is the case there's other ways of resolving this, i.e. PREFFERED_VERSION.

Why do you want that information? I assume for better traceability of the binary. Please add that info and some of your own research to the question.
